# framer-motion with storybook error in build environment

Tags: storybook, framer-motion

I'm building a UI library.

Is there anyone use framer-motion with storybook?

It works fine in storybook, but an error occurs in build environment.

Some people recommend downgrade but it doesn't work for me.

Does anyone have a problem similar to mine?

Answer (score 7):

Running in to the same issue here.
I think it's due to the new version of Framer-motion not being compatible with certain tools. I will debug today and let you know if i am able to find a solution.

**Edit**

Got it working!
Add the following to your .storybook/main.js file

```
module.exports = {
  // Any existing rules
  ...

  // The fix
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      type: "javascript/auto",
    });
    return config;
  }
}
```